# Issue with Group by mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a query

```
return $this->db->select ("SELECT `c_id`,`c_name`,(select count(`a_id`) nam from Admin_course_groups where fk_c_id = `c_id` and fk_g_id = $id)adm from admin_courses");
```

and output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [c_id] => 1
            [c_name] => Java - Basic Operators
            [adm] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [c_id] => 3
            [c_name] => JAVA Questions and Answers
            [adm] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [c_id] => 4
            [c_name] => Java - Collections Framework
            [adm] => 0
        )

)
```

So i want to get start date and end date from this query.so i tried

```
 return $this->db->select ("SELECT `c_id`,`c_name`,count(`a_id`) nam,start_date,end_date from admin_courses join Admin_course_groups on  fk_c_id = `c_id` where fk_g_id = $id group by `a_id`");
```

Which return only one result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (


[c_id] => 1
            [c_name] => Java - Basic Operators
            [nam] => 1
            [start_date] => 2018-01-01
            [end_date] => 2018-09-25
        )

)
```

Expected output

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [c_id] => 1
                [c_name] => Java - Basic Operators
                [nam] => 1
                [start_date] => 2018-01-01
                [end_date] => 2018-09-25
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [c_id] => 3
                [c_name] => JAVA Questions and Answers
                [adm] => 0
                [start_date] =>
                [end_date] =>
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [c_id] => 4
                [c_name] => Java - Collections Framework
                [adm] => 0
                [start_date] => 
                [end_date] => 
            )

    )
```

Table
**admin_courses**

```
c_id      |     C_name           |         C_desc | C_status
1           Java - Basic Operators        test        1
2          JAVA Questions and Answers     test2       1
3          Java - Collections Framework   test3        1
```

Table  **Admin_course_groups**

```
a_id | fk_c_id |fk_g_id|start_date|end_date
 1      1          2      2018-01-01 2018-09-25
```

Any help would be Appreciated.

Comment: Remove `group by a_id`

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya not working SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'manage.Admin_course_groups.start_date' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
error

Comment: You need to remove the group by part.

Comment: Try `group by c_id` instead of `group by a_id`.

Comment: @Arihant not working

Comment: Try `group by c_id, c_name` instead of `group by a_id`.

Comment: Left join instead of join

Comment: Try `group by c_id, c_name, start_date, end_date` instead of `group by a_id`. Also have the `count(a_id)` as  last in `Select` statement.

Comment: `SELECT c_id,c_name,start_date,end_date,count(a_id) nam`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of issues with your query that lead to it not returning all the results you want. Firstly, you are using a `JOIN` and there is only one matching row in `admin_course_groups` so that restricts you to one row. You should use a `LEFT JOIN` instead. Secondly, you are grouping by `a_id` when you should group by `c_id`. Finally after changing to a `LEFT JOIN` you will need to modify the `WHERE` clause to allow `fk_g_id` to be `NULL`. This query should give the results you want:

```
SELECT `c_id`, `c_name`, COUNT(`a_id`) AS nam, MIN(start_date), MIN(end_date)
FROM admin_courses c
LEFT JOIN admin_course_groups g
ON g.fk_c_id = c.`c_id` 
WHERE fk_g_id = 2 OR fk_g_id IS NULL
GROUP BY `c_id`
```

Output:

```
c_id    c_name                          nam     start_date  end_date
1       Java - Basic Operators          1       2018-01-01  2018-09-25
2       JAVA Questions and Answers      0       (null)      (null)
3       Java - Collections Framework    0       (null)      (null)
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4adee/7)

Comment: thanks for your reply..but i got an error like SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'manage.g.start_date' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by